# ActiveRecord conditional count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my application, I'm trying to sort items by views within the last 10 days. I'm using the Impressionist gem, which creates a model called impression and records every view here.

I've managed to get to this piece of code:

```
@items = Item.joins("left join impressions on impressions.impressionable_id = items.id and impressions.impressionable_type = 'Item'")
                   .select("count(distinct(ip_address)) as counter, impressionable_id, items.title, items.id, items.image")
                   .group('items.id')
                   .order("counter desc")
                   .page(params[:page])
                   .per_page(9)
```

This sorts the items by total unique views. However, I want to only count the impressions which have been made within the last 10 days. This led me to add a `where` method as such:

```
  time_range = (Time.now - 10.days)..Time.now

  @items = Item.joins("left join impressions on impressions.impressionable_id = items.id and impressions.impressionable_type = 'Item'")
   .select("count(distinct(ip_address)) as counter, impressionable_id, items.title, items.id, items.image")
   .where('impressions.created_at' => time_range)
   .group('items.id')
   .order("counter desc")
   .page(params[:page])
   .per_page(9)
```

However, this excludes the items which has no views, which is not what I want. These should be represented with 0 view.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: The `joins` will eliminate the records having no relation, use `includes(:impressions)` instead. See here: http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.ca/2011/12/rails-include-vs-joins.html ,  it says: "`:joins`
- It actually do an 'INNER JOIN' which filters the rows that don't have association." & "`:includes` it will do 'LEFT OUTER JOIN', which shows all the record from table."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use CASE, along with some modifications to make it run on heroku's postgres server.

```
  start_date = (Time.now - 10.days)
  end_date = Time.now
  joins("left join impressions on impressions.impressionable_id = items.id and impressions.impressionable_type = 'Item'")
      .select("count(distinct(case when (impressions.created_at BETWEEN '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}') then ip_address end)) as counter, impressionable_id, items.gender, items.title, items.id, items.image")
      .group('items.id', 'impressions.impressionable_id')
      .order("counter desc")
```